# phrasal verbs with particle FROM

Tags: phrasal-verbs

In the sentence -

> The boy saves his pet mouse from the cat.

what is the function of the prepositional phrase **from the cat**? I'm pretty sure it is not adjective describing MOUSE. I'm thinking ADVERB. do you agree? If it is, what type of adverb?

Comment: Are you sure of the tense of your main verb **save**? It sounds like a fact and every day doing instead of an event that happened in a time in the past.

Comment: @TasneemZh it can be a news title or a part of the story told in Present Simple

Comment: The PP "from the cat" is a complement of "saves"

Comment: @AndrewTobilko | It is hard to imagine such a sentence as a title in news, but yes, those are some possibilities. It could also be something from _describe what you see in the pictures_ exercises.

Answer (score 1):

> *The boy saves his pet mouse from the cat.*

"*His pet mouse from the cat" is not a constituent, so you are right that the PP is not modifying "mouse".

The PP "from the mouse" functions as **complement** of "saves". It's a complement, not a modifier like an adverb, because it is obligatory for this sense of "save", which means "keep safe from danger".